Rmail don't display text immediately when opening message
I'd like to have an overview of the parts of the email messages I receive when displaying a message; but rmail immediately opens the text part of the email pushing the other parts out of my small screen. I couldn't find any variable to customise this behaviour, any ideas?

Does the Emacs manual's section on Rmail's message displlay provide any enlightenment?

Nope! WHYARE15CHARACTERSREQUIREDTOCOMMENT
